# Why Facebook Graph API page/events is rate limited?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, rate-limiting

Only for one of my page with id `104813301239876` I get a rate limit. It says:

```
"error_user_msg": "You have exceeded asset access limit for the calling user. For asset type page, there is a limit to 3 instances the app can access for the caller."
```

though limit was set to 3.

[image]

Really strange, if I reduce limit to 2 or 1 it will work. Why? Why error message referes to limit = 3?